# Lock a thread after it finished executing

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, semaphore

So I have two threads that run infinite (well, until the program terminates) loops. The project is in Java 11.

The first thread is main loop that handles rendering and quick logic processing such as click events, etc.

The second thread is Loader thread. It handles big batches of data or resource-intensive tasks. Basically it prepares the data for the first thread, so the first thread doesn't stall for too long while calculating something and renders at a steady frame rate.

Here's the problem: I need to lock the second thread from the first one. But I need to ensure that this is only done AFTER the second thread finished its current task and is not in the middle of processing some data.

The way I had an idea to do this is for the first thread to merely give a signal for the second thread to lock, and the second thread processes that signal at the start (or end) of its new loop/iteration, and locks itself until it receives a signal to unlock. The way I wanted to do that is through Semaphore class, something like this:

```
private Semaphore = new Semaphore(1, true)
private boolean needsToLock = false;
private boolean locked = false;

// This is the loop of the second thread, pseudocode
while (true)
{
  if (needsToLock)
  {
    semaphore.aquire();
    locked = true;
  }

  semaphore.aquire();   // This will stall and wait if the conditional lock was initiated
  // do stuff
  semaphore.release();
}


// And these functions are called from main thread
public lockThread()
{
  needsToLock = true;
}

public releaseThread()
{
  semaphore.release();   // unlocks the thread and lets the loop to continue running
  locked = false;
}


// this function is tested by main thread to check if the thread is properly stalled
public isLocked()
{
  return locked;
}
```

I was wondering if there is some better ways to do this? I don't like several things about this idea, such as:

1. Giving public acess to releasing the semaphore
2. relying on the other thread to release it properly and not hang the thread eternally

Comment: Why do you think you need to 'lock' the other thread in the first place.  One thread can't force the other thread to be locked. You also have a data race in your code since 'locked' doesn't happen a happens-before edge.

Comment: I need it because the main thread needs to change some data that the second thread uses, and I can't have it changed anywhere in the middle of the second thread performing it's task, because then the result will be incorrect (half of the data calculated with an old variable, and half with the new one). I also don't see a race condition here. "locked" is changed in both cases after the semaphore is aquired. It is perfectly OK for my case if it's checked before it's changed but after the semaphore - it merely means that the main thread will do 1 extra iteration in the fringe case.

Answer (score 0):

I've completely changed my answer after reading the concrete problem description that you provided in a comment, below. I decided that this is a rare case where I would reach down to the most primitive form of inter-thread communication: `wait()` and `notify()`. Apologies in advance if you discover that there is some wheel that I am re-inventing here. I'm not aware of one, but then I don't know every design pattern on Earth these days.

Here's what I would do (Note: I didn't have time to actually test it):

```java
// Coordinates the activity of _one_ master thread and _one_ 
// worker thread.
//
public class SynchronousTurnstile {
    private Object mutex = new Object();
    private boolean isHoldRequested = false;
    private boolean isHolding = false;

    // Called by worker. Returns when it's safe for the worker to
    // proceed.
    //
    public passThroughTurnstile() {
        synchronized(mutex) {
            if (! isHoldRequested) {
                return;
            }

            isHolding = true;
            mutex.notifyAll();

            while (isHoldRequested) {
                mutex.wait();
            }
            isHolding = false;
        }
    }

    // Called by master to notify worker that it is not safe to 
    // proceed through the turnstile.
    // DOES NOT RETURN until the worker is holding at the turnstile.
    //
    public void lockTurnstile() {
        synchronized(mutex) {
            isHoldRequested = true;
            while (! isHolding) {
                mutex.wait();
            }
        }
    }

    // Called by master when it is again safe for worker to pass through.
    //
    public void unlockTurnstile() {
        synchronized(mutex) {
            isHoldRequested = false;
            mutex.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but then there is no way for the master thread to know if the background thread has actually finished its "performOneTask()" routine. We aquire it in the main thread, and then what? How do I tell that the loop actually finished and is now waiting on the semaphore/turnstile?

Comment: @VladVyatkin, The turnstile does what I thought you asked for: It provides a way for one thread to run freely, performing "tasks," except when some other thread says, "hold," in which case, it holds in between tasks. If that's not what you wanted, then you should post a new question to StackOverflow, and provide more detail about how you want the two threads to interact. (e.g., _why_ does the main thread want to "lock" the worker? _When_ does it unlock again? ...) You've told us about your idea for how to solve the problem, but so far, you've said little about what the problem actually is.

Comment: I think I actually provided all the information. Quote: "Here's the problem: I need to lock the second thread from the first one. But I need to ensure that this is only done AFTER the second thread finished its current task and is not in the middle of processing some data."

Comment: I don't know why you need the concrete problem, but if you must know - in my 3d "world" all object coordinates are counted from 0. But if you get too far the crummy GPU can't handle the precision loss that causes artifacting. That's why I need to move the world origin, and for that I need to make sure that it doesn't happen in the middle of something else calculating coordinates. Hence - I need to stop the processing thread and execute the switch, but ensure it doesn't happen in the middle of the task iteration. I can't have half of the mesh to be calculated with old origin, and half with new.

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps you at all. Can't you just accept an abstract problem without knowing my entire project? It's that simple: I need to execute a task in Thread A but only in-between iterations of Thread B. Thread A can't just sit and wait for the semaphore to be released by Thread B (because it's slow), that's why I need a more complex synchronization between them.

Comment: @VladVyatkin, The concrete example made the problem clear to me. Thank you, and see my updated answer (above).